# converting a message class for wrinting as a

Tags: java

I have a message class with some different fields and some getter/setters.
How do I convert this class so that I can write the binaray stream to a socket.
I do NOT want to serialize at all but I just want to raw the raw bytes represented in a class fields.

Thank you !!!

I am trying to do this but the bytes arent coming out correctly:

```
     public static byte[] serialize(Object obj) throws IOException {
        ByteArrayOutputStream b = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ObjectOutputStream o = new ObjectOutputStream(b);
        o.writeObject(obj);
        return b.toByteArray();
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "the binary stream"? It's not like there's exactly one possible representation. You absolutely do *not* want the raw bytes in the object representation - that would be absolutely useless as it would be implementation-specific.

Comment: Your object needs to implement `Serializable` so you can use it with `ObjectOutputStream`

Comment: I need my message to come across the socket without any serialization headers, just the raw byte of the the field values.  So if my class has integer of value 1 then when I convert to bytes the raw bytes will just show an integer value of 1. When I do the serialization it does not do that. So I think I should NOT do object serialiation. Are there other options?

Comment: You're going to have to write a function to write out each individual field then. I don't think you can do a one line "write the entire class" out.